# How to make the for loop wait for an event handler to finish? Android

Tags: android, for-loop, events, infinite-loop

I have a loop which iterates 10 times. Each time I update the question and the choices and check for the correct choice. The thing is, the loop does not wait for `setOnClickListner` to finish its job! it just ignores it and iterates till the end. Also, if I put the `counter` inside the listener, it just goes into an infinite loop and the screen turns to dark. How I can overcome this?

Note: the `counter` has been declared globally.

```
 for(;counter<10;counter++){
        questionTv.setText(questions[counter]);
        questionImage.setImageResource(images[counter]);
        choice1.setText(choices[counter][0]);
        choice2.setText(choices[counter][1]);
        choice3.setText(choices[counter][2]);
        choice4.setText(choices[counter][3]);
        choice1.setEnabled(true);
        choice2.setEnabled(true);
        choice3.setEnabled(true);
        choice4.setEnabled(true);
        choicesRg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,int checkedId){
                switch(checkedId){
                    case R.id.choice1:{
                        checkAnswer(answers,choice1,choice2,choice3,choice4,scoreTv); //a method to check the answer and do necessary modification. 
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.choice2:{
                        checkAnswer(answers,choice2,choice1,choice3,choice4,scoreTv);
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.choice3:{
                        checkAnswer(answers,choice3,choice2,choice1,choice4,scoreTv);
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.choice4:{
                        checkAnswer(answers,choice4,choice2,choice3,choice1,scoreTv);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is poor design, if you have 10 sets of questions it makes more sense to have 10 fragments, in a viewpager for example.

Comment: @JakeB ,sorry. I am just a beginner. I even do not know what is a fragment! Also, it is my first app hhhhhhh.

Answer (score 1):

Whipped this up quickly, however, like i said in my comment, there are better ways by design to do what you are doing, without loops, using Android components.

You have a list of questions, and predictably questions go from 1 to 10 (in your case), so lets increment the question number after each time you call `checkAnswer` and subsequently refresh the view:

```
private void setQuestions(int questionNum) {
        questionTv.setText(questions[questionNum]);
        questionImage.setImageResource(images[questionNum]);
        choice1.setText(choices[questionNum][0]);
        choice2.setText(choices[questionNum][1]);
        choice3.setText(choices[questionNum][2]);
        choice4.setText(choices[questionNum][3]);
        choice1.setEnabled(true);
        choice2.setEnabled(true);
        choice3.setEnabled(true);
        choice4.setEnabled(true);
        choicesRg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,int checkedId){
                switch(checkedId){
                    case R.id.choice1:{
                        checkAnswer(answers,choice1,choice2,choice3,choice4,scoreTv, questionNum); //a method to check the answer and do necessary modification.
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.choice2:{
                        checkAnswer(answers,choice2,choice1,choice3,choice4,scoreTv, questionNum);
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.choice3:{
                        checkAnswer(answers,choice3,choice2,choice1,choice4,scoreTv, questionNum);
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.choice4:{
                        checkAnswer(answers,choice4,choice2,choice3,choice1,scoreTv, questionNum);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

private void checkAnswer(List<String> answers, 
                         boolean choice1, 
                         boolean choice2, 
                         boolean choice3, 
                         boolean choice4, 
                         TextView scoreTv,
                         int questionNum) {
    // Do stuff
    setQuestions(questionNum++);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You really did great help!